# while loop, computing averages

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

Hello I am fairly new to python and would like to know where my program is failing and why.. thanks, the basic coding is as follows,

```
    grade = 0
    total = 0
    scorecount = 0
    while grade >=0:
        grade = raw_input("enter grade ->")
        grade = int(grade)
        total = total + grade
        total = int(total)
        scorecount = scorecount + 1
        scorecount= int(scorecount)
    average = total/scorecount
    print average
```

Comment: How is it "failing'?  What does failure look like?  Messages, output, etc.  would be helpful.  Perhaps you've been bitten by integer division.  If you divide two ints 4/5 you'll get zero, right?

Comment: It asks my to enter grade i enter 100 then 60, then i enter -1 to stop the while statement. instead of getting 80, the average of 100 and 60 i get 49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accept the grade, then add it to the average *even if it is -1*, since you don't check for `-1` until the loop starts again.

To quit a loop halfway through, use `break`. Then, you can write

```
while True: # loop 'forever' until break
    grade = raw_input("enter grade ->")
    grade = int(grade)
    if grade == -1:
        break # we're done
    # rest of processing...
```

Comment: thanks, i was confused and i had a feeling there needed to be something more in the coding but i didnt quite know what. Thank you sir.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the original code, not your modification.  I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be smarter to use a list to manage something like this.

```
grades = []

while True:
    grade = int(raw_input('Enter a grade: '))
    if grade < 0:
        break
    grades.append(grade)

print '\nAverage:', float(sum(grades)) / len(grades)
```

There are better ways to have the user break the loop than entering a negative grade, but there you go.

Comment: Sorry that i forgot to mention this, i am in high school and my teacher wants us to write the program like it is above. I'm am aware there are better ways but currently i have to break the loop with a negative grade.

Comment: My code does exactly that- and my apoligies, I accidentally wrote in a `return` instead of a `break`, I fixed it in an edit. Are you required to keep counters like that, or is there an allowance for a little creativity? You might get a pat on the back for doing a little out-of-class research, but then again I don't know your teacher. ;)

Comment: Hmm a couple of students attempted to do this same program in different ways similar to the one above but he just sort of denied them, I'm not saying learning these other methods wont help in the long run though, tomorrow i will look into them and do some more research since tonight i still have homework and for some reason, feel exhausted. Thanks to everyone who posted, goodnight.

Answer (score 0):

Your checking for -1 AFTER you change it, so you should check that the raw grade is that and break from the loop before processing.

Comment: Thank you, now how exactly do i do that...sorry.

Comment: Not a python programmer, but I think: